# get the function caller in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, callstack

I have a function `createStuff` which gets called when the html body is loaded

inside the function is a event listener  `btn.addEventListener("click", notes);`
which calls the `notes` function

clicking on the button does not display in the console that `createStuff` is invoked again

expected behavior would be that `createStuff` console.log would be visible because
the event listener is in `createStuff`

is there a way to display who invoked the function ?

```
  <body onload="createStuff()">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn" type="button">add</button>

      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="./function.caller.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
function notes() {
  console.log("gets called inner ---notes");
  // function caller
 

  const li = document.createElement("li");

  const liText = document.createElement("textarea");
  liText.setAttribute("cols", 12);
  liText.setAttribute("rows", 6);
  li.appendChild(liText);

  const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function createStuff() {
  const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click", notes);

  console.trace();

  console.log("gets called --- createNotes");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; clicking the button won't invoke `createStuff` again.

Comment: Instead of the `onload` inside the body tag, I would add something like `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  createStuff();  }, false);`  in a script tag at the bottom of the page.  So it waits for the DOM to load.. Then fires the function.

Comment: Did you mean to put the `console.trace` inside the `notes` function?

Comment: "*Is there a way to display who invoked the function?*" - yes, that's `console.trace`, but as you say `createStuff` does not *invoke* `notes`, in only installed it as an event listener. If you need this kind of info, you'll need to pass it in explicitly: `btn.addEventListener("click", e => notes(e, 'from createStuff'));`.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain  `installed it as an event listener`

Comment: @herbertmühlex `createStuff` binds the event listener to the button; it does not *call* the event listener. The event listener is called on the event.